# Glassfish5: JSF FacesServlet is not called

Tags: jsf, glassfish, glassfish-5

Glassfish5: JSF FacesServlet is not called.

example.ear

```
    example_ejb.jar
    example_web.war

    META-INF/application.xml
```

META-INF/application.xml

```
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd"
             version="8">
    
    <module>
        <ejb>example_ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>example_web.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>example_web</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>


    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

example_web.war

```
WEB-INF/web.xml
home.xhtml
```

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Faces Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Deployed example.ear to Glassfish5, successful.
But

http://localhost:8080/example_web/home.xhtml

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Set breakpoint in FacesServlet.java, the service() method is not called in debug mode.

Comment: Tried putting a plain html file next to the .xhtml file and retrieve that? No 404 then? Normally if the servlet is not called with the content being in the right location and actually deployed, you retrieve the plain unparsed content of the xhtml file and you **don't** get a 404.

Comment: adding home.html along with the home.xhtml, got the same 404 for the .html file. http://localhost:8080 says "Glassfish is running". There is no error or exception logs. The only message during deployment: Context path from ServletContext: /example_web differs from path from bundle: example_web|#].

Comment: So check what the actual deployment context path is. Not JSF related!. Change the title, tags and content of the question. Or better, remove this question and create a new one!

Comment: But the same contextPath works for web services. Web service method is invoked.

Comment: Might be... still not jsf related

Comment: war example works as expected. but could not find a working ear example that contains war.